# Solving scalar quantum field in 1+1D Milne space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, metric-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

So our line element is

\begin{equation}
ds^2=dt^2-a^2t^2dx^2
\end{equation} 
doing following coordinate transformation 
\begin{equation}
y^0=t\hspace{2pt}\cosh ax, \hspace{2pt}y^1=t\hspace{2pt}\sinh ax
\end{equation}
we get

\begin{equation}
ds^2=(dy^0)^2-(dy^1)^2
\end{equation}

Now finding Killing vectors is easy to obtain in this coordinate and they're 
\begin{eqnarray}
&&y^1\partial_{y^0}+y^0\partial_{y^1},\\
&&\partial_{y^0} ,\\
&&\partial_{y^1}
\end{eqnarray}

of which only $\partial_{y^0}$ is a timelike vector. Now transforming it (let's call this vector $K$) back to $(t,x)$ coordinate we get

\begin{equation}
K=\cosh ax\hspace{2pt}\partial_t-\frac{\sinh ax}{at}\partial_{x}
\end{equation}

For further reference I will write 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial y^{\nu^{'}}}{\partial x^\mu}=\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh ax & at\hspace{2pt}\sinh ax \\
\sinh ax & at\hspace{2pt} \cosh ax \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $x$ refers to $(t,x)$  and $y$ refers to $(y^0,y^1)$.

The given line element can also be written as

\begin{equation}
ds^2=e^{2a\eta}(d\eta^2-dx^2)
\end{equation}

where we have substituted $t=\frac{1}{a}e^{a\eta}$

Now coming to field equation of scalar field for the case of (1+1) Milne universe it can be written as following

\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(x) &=& \int \frac{dk}{2\pi}(a_k u_k(x)+a_k^{\dagger}u_k^*(x))\\
u_k(x,\eta) &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx} y(\eta)
\end{eqnarray}

where $y(\eta)$ satisfies

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2y}{d\eta^2}+(k^2+m^2\hspace{2pt}e^{2a\eta})y=0
\end{equation}

The above equation can be expressed as equation of Bessel function by substituting $z=e^{a\eta}$. Doing this we get

\begin{equation}
z^2\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+z\frac{dy}{dz}+(\frac{m^2}{a^2}z^2+\frac{k^2}{a^2})
\end{equation}
so we get 
\begin{equation}
y(t)=J_{\pm\frac{ik}{a}}(mt),\hspace{3pt}Y_{\pm\frac{ik}{a}}(mt), \hspace{3pt}H_{\pm\frac{ik}{a}}^{(1,2)}(mt)
\end{equation}

Now to find out which one is positive frequency with respect to the global timelike Killing vector I have to find out the which one of the above is eignefunction of the following form

\begin{equation}
K\hspace{3pt}u_k(x)=-i\omega u_k(x)
\end{equation}

where $\omega >0$ but the problem I'm facing is [following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511299/how-to-verify-the-following-function-is-an-eigen-function-of-the-given-operator) cause once I know how things work out for $J(x)$ others can be done since they're simply its linear combination.

Is my approach correct or am I making some conceptual mistakes?

Comment: Possibly relevant - https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.99.104308 or https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.10.3905